# SQL Insert Into Value with condition included

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to modify a session in my `Sessions` table. I need to be able to insert values into a specified row i.e. with a condition included although I'm not sure how.

Here is my code (I'm aware that I cannot do INSERT INTO > VALUES > WHERE but I'm trying to give you an idea of what I want to do).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TT_Modify_Session]
    @SessionName NVARCHAR(50),
    @TrainingName NVARCHAR(100),
    @Trainee NVARCHAR(20),
    @TrainingDate DATE,
    @SessionID INT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO dbo.TT_Sessions (SessionName, Trainee, TrainingDate, TrainingName)
        VALUES @SessionName, @Trainee, @TrainingDate, @TrainingName
        WHERE @SessionID = [SessionID] 

        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH

    RETURN @sessionID
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `[SessionID]` in relation to in your `WHERE`? You have no `FROM` clause.

Comment: Do you need `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` ? or you need `INSERT INTO [table] (columns) SELECT columns FROM [table] WHERE [SessionId] = @SessionId` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe code to "modify" values that already exist in the table.  That's an `UPDATE`...

*(`INSERT` adds a new row to a table, and leaves all pre-existing rows as they were...)*

```
UPDATE
  dbo.TT_Sessions
SET
  SessionName  = @SessionName,
  Trainee      = @Trainee,
  TrainingDate = @TrainingDate,
  TrainingName = @TrainingName
WHERE
  SessionID = @SessionID
```